# Get Authed Players Last Score Google Game API - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-play, google-play-services

I need to show Last score of specific Google Play Game API used Game

Let say this, i want to get last scores of "Rush Fight" Authed users using NodeJS.

how to implement this....

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with the concept of [Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards). When you create a leaderboard, the Google Play games services will take care of managing most aspects of this leaderboard for you.

> The typical process works like this:
>
> 1. At the end of a game (or at an appropriate moment that you've determined), the game submits the player's score to one or more leaderboards you've created for the game.
> 2. The Google Play games services checks if this score is better than the player's current leaderboard entry for the daily, weekly, or all-time score. If it is, the Google Play games services updates the corresponding leaderboards with the new score.
> 3. The Google Play games services sends a score report back to the game client. This report tells the client whether this is a new daily, weekly, or all-time high score. If it isn't, the Google Play games services will tell the client what the current daily, weekly, or all-time high score is for this player.
> 4. To retrieve a player's results for a leaderboard, you can requests a time frame (daily, weekly, or all-time), and specify whether or not the user wants to see a social or public leaderboard. The Games service performs all the necessary filtering, and then sends the results back to the client.
> 5. In cases where there are a lot of scores to report, the Games service sends back only the data for the top leaderboard scores. You can also retrieve raw score data for the top scores or the scores adjacent to the player's.

This [tutorial](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper) might also help. It's a Node.js module to scrape application data from the Google Play store. You can use the method [`app`](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper#app) to retrieve the full detail of an application.

Example:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);
```

Results:

```
{
  appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies',
  title: 'Panda vs Zombie: Elvis rage',
  summary: 'Help Rocky the Panda warrior to fight zombie games and save the Panda kind.',
  url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dxco.pandavszombies&hl=en',
  icon: 'https://lh6.ggpht.com/5mI27oolnooL__S3ns9qAf_6TsFNExMtUAwTKz6prWCxEmVkmZZZwe3lI-ZLbMawEJh3=w300',
  minInstalls: 10000,
  maxInstalls: 50000,
  score: 4.9,
.....
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to get specific Player Today High Score through His Google Plus(play) Authenticated Id! i want to get "Rush Fight" Game His/her High Score on that day!